# How do I use PDO to submit form values to a database?

Tags: php

Ok so I have added a new form to my site to add sites. Currently I am using a system that uses PDO in a database.php file which is called from method in an adminprocess.php file, which itself is called from the page on submit.

Of course I am quite confused about how to do this. I have built the method in database.php which is below:

```
function addNewSite($name, $region, $address, $suburb, $state, $postcode, $contactFirst, $contactLast, $contactMob, $contactEmail){
          $query = "SELECT sitename, region, state FROM ".TBL_SITES." WHERE sitename = :name and region = :region and state = :state";
          $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
          $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name, ':region' => $region, ':state' => $state));
          $count = $stmt->rowCount();

          if(!$stmt || $count < 1){
            return 1; 
          }

         $query = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_SITES." SET sitename = :name, region = :region, streetaddress = :address, suburb = :suburb, state = :state, postcode = :postcode, contact_firstname = :contactFirst, contact_lastname = :contactLast, contact_mobile = :contactMob, contact_email = :contactEmail";
         $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
         return $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name, ':region' => $region, ':address' => $address, ':suburb' => $suburb, ':state' => $state, ':postcode' => $postcode, ':contactFirst' => $contactFirst, ':contactLast' => $contactLast, ':contactMob' => $contactMob, ':contactEmail' => $contactEmail));
       }
```

I then created the processing method in adminprocess.php which looks like:

```
 /* User submitted add site form */
      else if(isset($_POST['addsite'])){
         $this->procAddSite();
```

and

```
function procAddSite(){
      global $database;
      $database->addNewSite();

      header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
     }
```

and the form that I want to send is:

```
<form action="adminprocess.php" method="post">
<table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $form->value("name"); ?>" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $form->error("name"); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Region:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="region" value="<?php echo $form->value("region"); ?>" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $form->error("region"); ?></td></tr>
<tr>
    <td>Street Address:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $form->value("address"); ?>" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $form->error("address"); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Suburb:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="suburb" value="<?php echo $form->value("suburb"); ?>" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $form->error("suburb"); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>State:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="state" value="<?php echo $form->value("state"); ?>" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $form->error("email"); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Postcode:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $form->value("postcode"); ?>" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $form->error("postcode"); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Contact First Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="contactFirst" value="<?php echo $form->value("contactFirst"); ?>" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $form->error("contactFirst"); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Contact Last Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="contactLast" value="<?php echo $form->value("contactLast"); ?>" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $form->error("contactLast"); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Contact Mobile:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="contactMob" value="<?php echo $form->value("contactMob"); ?>" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $form->error("contactMob"); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Contact Email:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="contactEmail" value="<?php echo $form->value("contactEmail"); ?>" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $form->error("contactEmail"); ?></td>
</tr>

<tr><td colspan="2" align="right">
<input type="hidden" name="addsite" value="1" />
<input type="submit" value="Add!" id="submit" /></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="left">
    <?php echo "<a href=".$config['WEB_ROOT'].$config['home_page'].">Back to Home Page</a>"; ?>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now it all seems to be working, right up until it hits the database.php function and I end up getting some errors:

Warning: Missing argument 1 for MySQLDB::addNewSite(), called in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/admin/adminprocess.php on line 256 and defined in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/include/database.php on line 66

Warning: Missing argument 2 for MySQLDB::addNewSite(), called in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/admin/adminprocess.php on line 256 and defined in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/include/database.php on line 66

Warning: Missing argument 3 for MySQLDB::addNewSite(), called in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/admin/adminprocess.php on line 256 and defined in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/include/database.php on line 66

Warning: Missing argument 4 for MySQLDB::addNewSite(), called in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/admin/adminprocess.php on line 256 and defined in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/include/database.php on line 66

Warning: Missing argument 5 for MySQLDB::addNewSite(), called in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/admin/adminprocess.php on line 256 and defined in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/include/database.php on line 66

Warning: Missing argument 6 for MySQLDB::addNewSite(), called in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/admin/adminprocess.php on line 256 and defined in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/include/database.php on line 66

Warning: Missing argument 7 for MySQLDB::addNewSite(), called in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/admin/adminprocess.php on line 256 and defined in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/include/database.php on line 66

Warning: Missing argument 8 for MySQLDB::addNewSite(), called in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/admin/adminprocess.php on line 256 and defined in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/include/database.php on line 66

Warning: Missing argument 9 for MySQLDB::addNewSite(), called in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/admin/adminprocess.php on line 256 and defined in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/include/database.php on line 66

Warning: Missing argument 10 for MySQLDB::addNewSite(), called in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/admin/adminprocess.php on line 256 and defined in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/include/database.php on line 66

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/include/database.php:66) in /home7/ultima19/public_html/tesg/admin/adminprocess.php on line 258

now my question is, Where am I supposed to declare those arguments??

I'm sorry about the long winded question, But I am trying to learn this PDO stuff lol

Comment: You're calling the method `addNewSite` in your `adminprocess.php` file, but not passing any parameters. That's where you need to add the parameters - I assume you'll just need `$_POST['name']`, and so on

Comment: It appears that question has nothing to do with PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the errors because the function addNewSite declared in database.php is expecting the variables $name, $region, $address, $suburb, $state, $postcode, $contactFirst, $contactLast, $contactMob, $contactEmail to be passed to it.

But in adminprocess.php where you call this function, you are not supplying any variables.

eg)

```
function procAddSite(){
  global $database;

  //no variables supplied!!!
  $database->addNewSite();

  header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
 }
```

You need to pass the variables from the form which you have submitted. These will be available in the $_POST array and referenced using the 'name' element have specified in your form.

You should be able to do something like this to fix your problem:

```
 function procAddSite(){
  global $database;

  //we have variables supplied now which were submitted from the form :)
  $database->addNewSite($_POST['name'], $_POST['region'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['suburb'], $_POST['state'], $_POST['postcode'], $_POST['contactFirst'], $_POST['contactLast'], $_POST['contactMob'], $_POST['contactEmail]);

  header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
 }
```

You could also just pass $_POST to function addNewSite and extract the $_POST array elements out in that function instead of passing them in as parameters.

Hope the above helps.

Comment: Hi arkyc, Thanks for your response. Sorry I had to leave work and have only just got a chance to jump back on in the last half hour. What you have said makes sense, and in fact I originally tried doing this by using the $name = $_POST['name']; method.

Both of these ways seem to avoid errors, however, there is nothing populated into the database, so i figured I had completely missed something

Comment: No problems. I actually took too long to write my answer up (was meant to be working at the same time ;) ) and some of the other good (and more experienced) people on here already answered within that time. Glad it helped you out though. Don't forget to protect your code from sql injection. You'll find plenty of references to that on stackoverflow on how to do that :)

Comment: Hi arkyc, actually thats what i'm trying to say. It actually hasn't helped. I'm assuming I have a mistake in my code somewhere, and I can't find where. There aren't any errors any more but the database is not populating. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry please excuse my manners…….its HAS helped, just not entirely. I do appreciate your help.

Comment: Oops. My apologies. I thought you were speaking in the past tense. Can you tell if your $_POST array elements have any values in them? eg) what's the value in $_POST['name']?

I'd now check that your addNewSite function is getting the values you expect to see if it's still a problem with passing variable values, or now it's a different issue with your PDO code.



Anybody else, feel free to jump in with suggestions :)

Comment: Oh, another thing I noticed (won't fix problem but it should simplify your code) - You're hitting the database twice. 1. To see if the row exists before you insert, and 2. To insert into the database if the row does not exist.

If you set the flag on the database columsn to not allow duplicate entries, you can just try to insert into the database. If a duplicate exists, it will error, and you can handle it from there. That way you don't need to do your first select from the database. Just a suggestion. Less code means easier to work out where bugs are.

Comment: $_POST array is spitting out the correct info. I have just logged into the PHPMyAdmin and the server has changed!! they did an update last night. I dunno if that is what caused it but it is now working correctly, and I can't see what I have changed to make it work!! thanks you for your help mate i appreciate it!!

Comment: Fantastic! Glad you got a positive result :)